# Issue regarding Payumoney success url

Tags: php, sql, payment-gateway, payumoney

As i have integrated **Payumoney** payment gateway for the first time ,so according to my information after successful payment the payment gateway is redirected to success url where we can save the useful information to the database.
But in my case,sometime it happens that the user had done payment but more than 1 entry are inserted to the database may be because of calling of success url for multiple time but the payment deduction happens only once.It happens only sometime else everything works fine.

Please give me any suggestion for resolving this issue

Comment: Without seeing code, we can't help.

Comment: @BenM As mentioned the code works fine ,but in some cases multiple entries happens in database.when we check the code works fine but in some cases we came across the issue.Please help if you can

Comment: The payment callback method should be Idempotent i.e. if the same URL is hit multiple times by the payment gateway, it should handle it gracefully.  That way it would be easier for you to handle webhooks as well.
_An idempotent method means that the result of a successful performed request is independent of the number of times it is executed._

Comment: @MunishChandel Thanks for your reply But it happens only with 5% of member So we can't find issue in our code.  So Please give me any suggestion for resolving this issue if you can...............

Comment: @RaghunathRaut What issues these members face? If database is creating double records for 5% payments, so its an issue with the code. What if user explicitly presses F5 after successfully payment?

Comment: @MunishChandel It's not a payment related issue, Payment is done successfully but double record get's inserted into database